# Only download a certain amount of files per second - "decrease" the download speed

Tags: java, download, nio, http-status-code-503

It appears to me that my server only allows 60 files to be downloaded per second, but I have 63 of them - all tiny, YAML files. As a result, the last 3 files don't get downloaded and throw error 503. I am using Baeldung's NIO example:

```java
public static void downloadWithJavaNIO(String fileURL, String localFilename) throws MalformedURLException {
        String credit = "github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/core-java-modules/core-java-networking-2/src/main/java/com/baeldung/download/FileDownload.java";

        URL url = new URL(fileURL);
        try (
            ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(url.openStream());
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(localFilename);
            FileChannel fileChannel = fileOutputStream.getChannel()
        ) {
            fileChannel.transferFrom(readableByteChannel, 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
    }
```

I was thinking of saving currentTimeMillis somewhere and checking if a second had passed by the time the 61th file is pending. But are there any other good ideas?

Comment: Download the first 60, followed by a `Thread.sleep(1000);` and the remaining 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `FileChannel.transferFrom`: An invocation of this method may or may not transfer all of the requested bytes.

So I am not sure whether it works in all cases. Maybe with those small files.

I would first try a correct (non-optimized) version:

```
public static void downloadWithJavaNIO(String fileURL, String localFilename)
        throws MalformedURLException {
    URL url = new URL(fileURL);
    Path targetPath = Paths.get(localFilename);
    try (InputStream in = url.openStream()) {
        Files.copy(in, targetPath);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.getLogger(getClass().getName()).log(Level.ERROR, fileURL, e);
    }        
}
```

- How fast now? Does it still need throttling? (slowing down, waiting)
- Does the capacity error still persist?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply! I managed to use a Thread#sleep in order to wait for a second. It indeed was the server problem that only allowed 60 usages per second. I found no harm in my Thread#sleep, because this particular case only happens once while ever using my application and only in the very beginning of it, so nothing would be damaged. If I will ever decide to get rid of that hacky way, I'll look into your response.

Comment: @jamberry thanks for the undeserved flowers (points). 60 Downloads per second can be solved differently. Try using one single URL connection on `url` and then several InputStreams on the same connection.